# duplicate rows after join the same table in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have sub-query that calculates some sums. And based on the value in column Saldo, I wanna manipulate and subtract some date columns. My problem is that I get duplicate rows.

I want to have one row of each FinID,and if the BrojDok is the same, I want to subtract the dates based on a value from Saldo column. My `datediff` is working. But there are duplicate rows. How can I manage that?

I tried with `DISTINCT`, but it just gives me the first row unique. And if in a inner join I add to join on a `b.FinId = P2.Fin` my Number of Days will always be zero,since every row will join on itself.

FinID is the PK of my table

This is my query:

```
SELECT P2.FinID
        ,P2.Firma
        ,P2.BrojDok
        ,P2.DatumVal
        ,P2.Saldo 
        ,P2.SaldoTotal2
        ,NumberOfDays = IIF(P2.SaldoTotal2<0
                            ,0
                            ,IIF(P2.SaldoTotal2<1
                                    ,(DATEDIFF(DAY,P2.DatumVal, b.DatumVal))
                                    ,0)
                            )
FROM
(
    SELECT P1.FinID
        , P1.Firma
        ,P1.BrojDok
        ,P1.DatumVal
        ,P1.Saldo
        ,P1.SaldoTotal
        ,SaldoTotal1 = IIF(P1.SaldoTotal<0
                            ,0
                            ,IIF(P1.SaldoTotal>1
                                    ,1
                                    ,0)
                            )
        ,SaldoTotal2 = IIF(P1.SaldoTotal<0
                            ,0
                            ,IIF(P1.SaldoTotal<1
                                    ,0
                                    ,1)
                            ) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT P.FinID
                ,P.Firma
                ,P.BrojDok
                ,P.DatumVal
                ,P.Saldo 
                ,SaldoTotal = SUM(Saldo) OVER (PARTITION BY BrojDok ORDER BY FinID)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT a.FinID
                    ,a.Firma
                    ,a.Konto
                    ,a.NazivKonta
                    ,a.NazFirme
                    ,a.BrojDok
                    ,a.DatumVal
                    ,a.Valuta
                    ,Saldo = Sum(IIf(a.[Konto] Like '2%'
                                        ,a.[Duguje] -a.[Potrazuje]
                                        ,a.[Potrazuje] -a.[Duguje])
                                )
            FROM tblFinansijskiPodaci a 
            WHERE a.Firma = 1 
                AND a.Konto = 2040
                AND a.Partner = 1137
            GROUP BY a.FinID
                    ,a.Firma
                    ,a.NazFirme
                    ,a.Konto
                    ,a.NazivKonta
                    ,a.BrojDok
                    ,a.DatumVal
                    ,a.Valuta
                    ,a.Duguje
                    ,a.Potrazuje
        ) AS P
        GROUP BY FinID
                ,Firma
                ,BrojDok
                ,Saldo
                ,DatumVal
    ) AS P1
    GROUP BY P1.FinID
            ,P1.Firma
            ,P1.BrojDok
            ,P1.DatumVal
            ,P1.Saldo
            ,P1.SaldoTotal
) AS P2 
INNER JOIN tblFinansijskiPodaci b ON b.BrojDok=P2.BrojDok
GROUP BY P2.FinID
        ,P2.Firma
        ,P2.BrojDok
        ,P2.Saldo
        ,P2.SaldoTotal
        ,P2.SaldoTotal1
        ,P2.SaldoTotal2
        ,P2.DatumVal
ORDER BY BrojDok
```

This is my result:

[image]

This is what I would like to get for the BrojDok 1379. But this is the result without inner join, so my Number of Days are not working.

I need to subtract dates based on value from Saldo column.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected result? For FinId=17751 what do you expect as result?

Comment: As I said on your previous question about this earlier I think you need to simplify your query here. It is was over complicated to have 4 nested select statements all from the same rows in the same table.

Comment: I edited the question to show expected result.

Comment: Can you provide the table structure and sample data for tblFinansijskiPodaci?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do account balance calculations, is that accurate? Your query is overly complicated and could probably be simplified quite a bit, but we'd need to know what business logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: Yes,balance is the goal..
I have Saldo,that is the sum column of my balance- it works fine. After that I have a running sum with partition,because I have documents(BrojDok)  with the same BrojDoc. I need to join the table to itself,because if my Saldo column is between 0 and 1,I need to subtract DatumVal for the same BrojDoc. If Saldo is  > 1 I need to subtract DatumVal with the todays date.And if Saldo is <0,Saldo should be zero.

Comment: I have managed to eliminate duplicates with the HAVING clause..I am showing only the records that are bigger than zero and do not have the same id. Now I am showing only every record to another difference, no duplicates